# Не запускаяется автоматическая отладка и запуск .cpp файла в VS Code

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-code

Недавно начал работать и писать маленькие программки на c++ в vs code. Месяй назад все настроил и поначалу все отлично работало, но позже почему-то перестало. Переустановил vs code, MinGW, но все равно не работает. В чем заключается проблема: я поставил плагин c/c++, нажал ctrl+shift+p, выбрал g++, пробую запустить .cpp файл, создается .exe этого файла, но не происжодит автоматический запуск в теримнале как раньше. На f5 тоже не работает, то есть просто собирается exe, и ничего не происходит, как это исправить и сделать, чтобы происходил автоматический запуск и можно было работать с отладчиком?

Comment: Установить набор с cmake?

Comment: можете, пожалуйста, объяснить доходчивее?

Comment: cmake - это не отладчик. если не происходит запуск программы (хоть в каком то виде), может в программе есть ошибки и она не компилируется/не линукуется (а учитывая упоминание двух файлов, думаю, там есть проблема с линковкой).

Comment: Я думаю, это связано с недавно вышедшими обновлениями. У меня тоже не работает отладчик.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была дейсвительно в новой версии плагина, поставил старую версию, и все заработало, спасибо огромное!